# What is the safest way to importing a local postgresql dump to heroku?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I have created a postgresql dump of my local database,however it contains sensitive data. I don't want to make it public in Amazon S3 as per the instructions on Heroku [(Export & Import data)](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#export) state.

This is what I am trying to do to restore the database:

```
heroku pgbackups:restore HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_DB_URL 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/mylink/mydb.dump'

HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_DB_URL  <---restore---  mydb.dump

 !    WARNING: Destructive Action
 !    This command will affect the app: app-name
 !    To proceed, type "app-name" or re-run this command with --confirm app-name

> app-name

Retrieving... done

 !    An error occurred and your restore did not finish.
 !    The backup url is invalid. Use `pgbackups:url` to generate a new temporary URL
```

If I make the dump public in Amazon S3, it works.

Is there a safe way to to import this dump into the Heroku's postgresql database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Connect directly to your Heroku database via tools like PGAdmin and restore it directly into the database. Use the output of `heroku config` to get your database URL to get the credentials you need.